# how to sort an array of arrays by three or more elements (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have csv file with 14 columns and I want to sort it in ruby by 6th column then by 2nd and then by 11th column.

There is nice method .sort_by but it works only for two columns, doesn't it. And `array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[2], e[0],e[1]],}` doesn't work.

so let's say in the sample below I want it to be sorted by 3rd,1st,2nd columns

```
array_of_arrays = [[1,9,'a'],[2,2,'a'], [2,6,'b'], [1,3,'a'], [2,1,'b']]

array_of_arrays.each {|line| puts line.inspect }
puts
array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[2], e[0]]} .each {|line| puts line.inspect }
```

but the result is not as desired

```
[1, 9, "a"]
[2, 2, "a"]
[2, 6, "b"]
[1, 3, "a"]
[2, 1, "b"]

[1, 9, "a"]
[1, 3, "a"]
[2, 2, "a"]
[2, 6, "b"]
[2, 1, "b"]
```

Comment: There is a comma before `}` in your example `array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[2], e[0],e[1]],}`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: exactly and that's why didn't work for me. :-) at least others can find answer and also learn that one extra comma makes big difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
array_of_arrays = [[1,9,'a'],[2,2,'a'], [2,6,'b'], [1,3,'a'], [2,1,'b']]

array_of_arrays.each {|line| p line }
puts
array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[2], e[0], e[1]]} .each {|line| p line }
```

Produces the following output for me:

```
[1, 3, "a"]
[1, 9, "a"]
[2, 2, "a"]
[2, 1, "b"]
[2, 6, "b"]
```

That's what you want, right?

Comment: To take DRY to its crazy limits, I'd consider: sort_by { |a| [2, 0, 1].collect { |i| a[i] } }

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: I have just used your dry solution.Great.I have my elements I want to sort by in an array so I can change the order and add anyone at any time without changing the code at all!!!!

Comment: @Radek, I wasn't even thinking of user-determined sort order when I added that comment.  Nice job!

Comment: How about an array of arrays of n elements? Without writing e[0],e[1]..e[n]. Not worth new question I think